# What would be the cause of a python script that I cannot run directly?

Tags: python, linux, terminal

As of late I've started trying to get back into programming. Upon attempting to run a previously made script (Will follow) just to see if I left it in working condition I'm met with two errors after a couple seconds of processing. Examining the code it seems correct but attempting again leads to the same result as expected. I ran it through the python debugger (`python -m pdb`) it ran flawlessly. Continuing that train of thought I tried running it through the python interpreter as `python luhn.py` again, flawless.

This particular box is Linux Sabayon 64bit (Python version 2.7.5), which is simliar to the system the script was originally written on, also sabayon 64bit. What might be the cause? I've tried resetting the terminal (both with `stty sane` and `reset`) to no avail.

Luhn.py

```
# Luhn Check in python
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

def generate():
  card = []
  for i in range(0,16):
    card.append(random.randrange(0,9))
  return card

def compress(number):
  result = 0
  strNum = str(number)
  if len(strNum) >= 2:
    result = compress(int(strNum[0]) + int(strNum[1]))
  else:
    result = number
  return result

def addition(card):
  total = 0
  for i in range(0,16,2):
    total += compress( card[i]*2 )
  for i in range(1,16,2):
    total += int(card[i])
  return total

cardNumber = generate()
print cardNumber

checksum = addition(cardNumber)%10
if (cardNumber[15]+(10-checksum)) in range(0,9):
  cardNumber[15] += (10-checksum)
elif (cardNumber[15]-checksum) in range(0,9):
  cardNumber[15] -= checksum

print cardNumber, addition(cardNumber)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#!/usr/bin/python` should be on the first line. The OS looks at the first two bytes (`#!`) to determine what the file you're asking it to execute is.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Luhn Check in python
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Swap these around. `#!/usr/bin/python` must be the very first thing on the very first line.